# Where to ask design related questions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

I must say I'm really glad I found SO, and it's a very valuable resource.

But it seems questions not specific enough goes unanswered, and this is quite understandable.

Do you know any other sites more suitable for discussing application <strike>design</strike> architecture?

Comment: belongs to meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application design question are fine to ask here as long as they're specific. The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) lists:

- a specific programming problem
- a software algorithm
- software tools commonly used by programmers
- matters that are unique to the programming profession

and application design issues certainly fall into that last category, and probably the second as well.

Comment: At least explain the downvote, guys so I can either fix or delete the answer.

Comment: My design related question has perhaps not been specific enough, but they haven't been closed either (not my downvote btw)

Comment: true. upvoted the answer.

Comment: Which one, @simendsjo, I can have a look if you want. No guarantees that I can answer it.

Comment: I'm still very new here, first month, so I might be better at asking the questions after a while too.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116073/problems-designing-mapping-dynamic-data-entry-value-store

Comment: Love to help you out on that one, @simendsjo but nhibernate is a bit out of my area of expertise. A couple of things though: (1) It was only asked two hours ago so you may find the other side of the planet can help you out when they get a look at it. (2) If there are no answers after a couple of days you can (a) edit it (I think that pushes it back to the front page) or (b) offer a bounty to try and convince more people to act on it.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>ask [here](http://doctype.com/) - http://doctype.com/</strike>

### EDIT

After getting clarity from comments -

It is perfectly ok to ask questions about application archtiecture/design here on stackoverflow, in fact this is the only right place for asking such questions as of now. You might prefer to tag them with `ooad`, `architecture`, `design` or some other more relevant tags.

voting to close this question since this question itself should have been asked on [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: I didn't mean visual design, I meant designing the application itself.

Comment: do you mean architecture ?

Comment: Yes, architecture is a better wording :) Thanks